# How do I make an empty Int variable?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make an Int variable but I can't set it to zero. I need it to be empty. I've tried:

```
let variable: Int
```

But that does nothing. I want to do something like this:

```
Let variable: Int = (Nothing)
```

Like a placeholder sort of. What is something I can use that isn't a number?

Comment: Use optional to handle nil value

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: Actually you are *trying to make an Int* **constant**. 

Comment: What do you mean by "*But that does nothing*"?

Answer (score 4):

Since empty constant is nonsense, use the following:

```
var myNumber: Int?
```

Any type that follows by a **question mark** (`?`) called optional and can be empty (nil)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Since I had to convert text fields to integers it kept coming up with errors

Comment: @Evan So correct the errors and move on. This is the correct way to do what you are asking for.

Comment: Yeah ok, makes sense.

Comment: ‘Var myText: String?’ for optional string

Answer (score 0):

Import UIkit

func isLeap(year: Int) {

```
let aYear = year

if aYear.isMultiple(of: 4){
    print("YES")
}else{
    print("NO")
}
```

}
isLeap(year: 2022)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33203375)